# check for mutations to original array/list

Tags: javascript

Решал различные задачки с помощью `JavaScript'a`. И споткнулся на такой: Цель, удалить минимальное значение из массива, при том, что расположение элементов не должно меняться, с задачей я вроде как справился, но сайт не пропускает, один тест не проходит. Пишет, что нужно проверять на мутированный массив.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
    var min, minindex;
    min = numbers[0];
    minindex = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if(min > numbers[i]) {
        min = numbers[i];
        minindex = i;
      }
    }
    numbers.splice(minindex, 1)
    return numbers;
  }
```

Что я делаю не так и какую проверку я вообще должен сделать? Задачка с codewars

Comment: Красным по чёрному написано — вы изменили массив, который `numbers`. Что сделать — не изменять `numbers`

Answer (score -1):

В аргумента вы получаете **ссылку** на массив который передался из теста, не копию массива. В коде Вы мутируете(изменяете) его через функцию splice. Решение в том чтобы сделать копию массива: `numbers = [...numbersInput]`. Или же можно воспользоваться решением которое не мутирует массив.

```js
function removeSmallest (numbersInput) {
  var numbers, min, minindex;
  numbers = [...numbersInput]; // копия массива
  min = numbers[0];
  minindex = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (min > numbers[i]) {
      min = numbers[i];
      minindex = i;
    }
  }
  numbers.splice(minindex, 1)
  return numbers;
}

console.log(removeSmallest([2, 50, 51, 60]))
```

Вот мой вариант решения и вариант как можно сделать по вашей идее но через `findIndex`:

```js
console.log(removeSmallest([2, 50, 51, 60]))
console.log(removeSmallest2([2, 50, 51, 60]))

function removeSmallest (numbers) {
  const min = Math.min(...numbers) // преобразвывает массив в аргументы
  
  return numbers.filter(i => i !== min) // это не мутирует исходный массив, а возвращает модифицированый
}

function removeSmallest2 (numbersInput) {
  let numbers = [...numbersInput] // копия массива
  const min = Math.min(...numbers)
  const minIndex = numbers.findIndex(i => i === min)
  
  numbers.splice(minIndex, 1)
  
  return numbers;
}
```